# firebug alternative in internet explorer

Tags: html, css

i am searching for firebug alternative for internet explorer 8 . i tried the firebug lite . just by embedding the java script code in my hmtl files but its not working effectively.

my website way2enjoy.com is working fine in all browser except internet explorer 8 . when the users log in to their account the middle part disappears.
there are three columns left middle and side but the middle disappears in ie8. i am not able to check as i dont know how to debug css in IE8 . i tried all sort of manipulation by reducing CSS width but unable to solve the issue.

the sample login id and password is

username   demo

password   demo

Comment: You should mark your site as NSFW, there are a few questionable images in there. Also, your markup is all out of whack, you should hunt down and fix all of those errors you have with the validator: http://validator.w3.org/.

Comment: there  is nothing to mark it as NSFW .what you found please tell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use IE8 Developer tools. Press <kbd>F12</kbd>, this tools are embedded

Comment: i tried but with that it is very difficult to trace the error like firebug

Answer (score 2):

IE8 contains its own built in developer tool which you can access by hitting <kbd>F12</kbd> or Tools>Developer Tools.  It is not as nice as firebug in ff, but it can be useful for debugging.

If your looking for a client side debugging tool that is as robust as Firebug for Firefox your not going to find it because one does not exist.

Comment: i tried but  with that it is very difficult to trace the error like firebug

Comment: can anyone tell how to find the errors in my css for way2enjoy.com after login as in ie8 it gives error.  username is demo and password is demo

Comment: just for everyones info this site is borderline nsfw

Comment: I am referring to your website.  I wouldn't want my boss walking by while looking at it.

Comment: which page you saw . if you dont mind please tell what you have seen . i dont think anything is there. please tell what you have seen .and if you know how to fix the problem in ie then it will be great

Answer (score 2):

There is the Firebug bookmarklet called [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite). It works in pretty much every browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Microsoft's [Developers Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18359).